# How set more than Max stock quantity on add to card if user adds more in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I use 'woocommerce_add_to_cart' action hook to add a product to cart even if user add more than Max stock quantity, but it returns "You can not add that amount of ... to the card because there is not enough stock (10 remaining)" .
How can I overcome this question?

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart_qty', 10, 6 );
function add_to_cart_qty( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, 
 $cart_item_data ){

 $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
 $product_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

 if( $quantity > $product_stock ){
     WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $quantity );
 }
}
```

Comment: Enabling backorder at product level if you are managing stock.